# How to define and test for a null string in AWS CloudFormation template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation template that accepts this parameter

```
TargetGroupName:
  Type: String
  Description: 'Parameter to override target group name'
  Default: ''
```

However, instead of an empty string as default, how can I define is as a Null string, like this?  I know **Null is NOT a valid keyword**, but I wanted to illustrate what I wanted to do.

```
TargetGroupName:
  Type: String
  Description: 'Parameter to override target group name'
  Default: Null
```

And then, how can I set a condition to test for the Null string, like this?

```
Conditions:
  CreateTargetGroup:
    !Not [ !Equals [ !Ref TargetGroupName, Null ] ]
```

Of course the keyword `Null` throws a CloudFormation script validation exception since it's NOT a valid keyword.

Comment: Where did you find that "Null" is a valid keyword?

Comment: It's NOT. I updated my OP to clarify my question.

Comment: I don't understand. There is no "Null" string. Its only an empty string `""`. You use empty string. There is nothing other than that.

Comment: IOW, I can't do what I want to do since CloudFormation does NOT have a Null string. Is there an equivalent?

Comment: Yes, sadly CFN is rather limited and lucks many features that you would find any any other programing language. You can have a look at terraform of CDK.

Comment: But what do you consider a Null string in CloudFormation? How's that would be different then an Empty string in this context?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Parameters:

TargetGroupName:
    Description: 'Parameter to override target group name'
    Type: String
    Default: ""

Condition:

  IsTargetGroupNameEmpty:  !Equals [!Ref "TargetGroupName", ""]
```

And then in every resource that you don't want to create just pass this line:

```
!If [ IsTargetGroupNameEmpty, [ !Ref <RESOURCE_NAME> ], !Ref "AWS::NoValue" ]
```

Please take a look on this docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html#cfn-pseudo-param-novalue

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that today.