# How to add/delete keys to an existing Secret in AWS SecretsManager with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-secrets-manager

Here is my CloudFormation (CFN) template that creates the secret named `MySecret` in AWS SecretsManager.

```
Resources:
  MySecret:
    Type: "AWS::SecretsManager::Secret"
    Properties:
      Name: MyDatabaseSecret
      Description: Secret for Database Connection
      SecretString: !Sub |
        {
          "DBUserName": "",
          "DBPassword": "",
          "DBPort":""
        }
```

After creating this secret using this CFN template, I started updating the secret values manually.

At some point, I wanted to add another key named `DBName` to this same secret with empty value like `"DBName": ""`, or, delete the key `"DBPort"`, using the same CFN template. But, for any key modification using the CFN update, I need to provide values for the existing keys as well. Otherwise, the CFN update will overwrite the values with the empty values from the template. I'd like the CFN to get (resolve) the values of the existing keys from the Secret and update them back. Is it possible?

I prefer a CloudFormation solution. If not, then AWS CDK with Python also will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like the CFN to get (resolve) the values of the existing keys from the Secret and update them back. Is it possible?

No, at least in a single deployment it is not possible and if you [retrieve the secret value](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/cfn-example_reference-secret.html) and assign it back, it will create a circular dependency if you reference to itself.

---

To resolve the circular dependency, you need to do a two phase deployment. First deployment, create your secret. Second deployment, grab your Secret's ARN and update your CFN template to get the Secret value.

```
Resources:
  MySecret:
    Type: "AWS::SecretsManager::Secret"
    Properties:
      Name: MyDatabaseSecret
      Description: Secret for Database Connection
      SecretString: !Sub |
        {
          "DBUserName": "{resolve:secretsmanager:<thisSecretArn>:SecretString:DBUserName::}}",
          "DBPassword": "{{resolve:secretsmanager:<thisSecretArn>:SecretString:DBPassword::}}",
          "DBPort": "{{resolve:secretsmanager:<thisSecretArn>:SecretString:DBPort::}}"
        }
```

CDK Psuedocode:

```
        from aws_cdk import (
            aws_secretsmanager as secrets,
            SecretValue    
        )

        secret_arn = 'secret_arn' # my_secret arn hard-coded cause can't reference to itself before creating it.

        pw = SecretValue.secrets_manager(
            secret_id=secret_arn,
            json_field='DBPassword'
        ).to_string()

        un = SecretValue.secrets_manager(
            secret_id=secret_arn,
            json_field='DBUserName'
        ).to_string()

        port = SecretValue.secrets_manager(
            secret_id=secret_arn,
            json_field='DBPort'
        ).to_string()

        dbname = SecretValue.secrets_manager(
            secret_id=secret_arn,
            json_field='DBPort'
        ).to_string()

        my_secret = secrets.Secret(
            self, "Secret",
            secret_object_value={
                "DBUserName": SecretValue.unsafe_plain_text(un),
                "DBPassword": SecretValue.unsafe_plain_text(pw),
                "DBPort": SecretValue.unsafe_plain_text(port),
                # Adding/removing works
                # "DBName": SecretValue.unsafe_plain_text(dbname),
            }
        )
```

You can also put the Secret ARN as a parameter and create a logic like this:

```
        _secret_arn = secret_arn # Stack parameter

        pw = SecretValue.secrets_manager(
            secret_id=secret_arn,
            json_field='DBPassword'
        ).to_string() if _secret_arn else ""
```

---

You can use [GenerateSecretString](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-secretsmanager-secret.html#cfn-secretsmanager-secret-generatesecretstring) to generate a random password. For keys like `DBUserName` or `DBPort`, you can use [CFN Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) with your default value. And if you want to update the value, you need update it via CFN and not manually.

Comment: 1) Updating CFN created secret values manually is not editing the managed resource manually, and it will not create a drift. A CFN managed secret will show in drift if you edit the other properties except the values. Values are updated manually in a lot of cases. 2) `GenerateSecretString` is not an option for me. These Secret values are used on-prem in their application configs as well. 3) You also stated 'probably' in your answer. I expected you to answer something that you know for sure.

Comment: Hey Rafiq, I stand corrected about the drift. I updated my answer and tested by retrieving the secret.

Comment: 1) It's a lot better now. Values defined like this `"DBUserName": "{{resolve:secretsmanager:${MySecretArn}:SecretString:DBUserName::}}"` work, where `${MySecretArn}` represents the corresponding parameter defined at the top. 2) However, it does not give me a complete solution. I'm OK to deploy in two phases. In first phase the `MySecretArn` parameter will have no value. The second and subsequent phases  the `MySecretArn` parameter will have a value, but I have to change value from `""` to `"{{resolve.......::}}"`.  Can we use condition to use this based on what `MySecretArn` has?

Comment: Also, I could not test your instructions using CDK yet. Do you think `"DBPassword": SecretValue.unsafe_plain_text(pw)` can display the the value of `pw` in the generated CFN template or in CFN logs?

Comment: 1) I think it's possible, you can use `Condition`. Check this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/64588255/22277802 2)`SecretValue.unsafe_plain_text(pw)` no it won't display it in plain text. The CFN template I posted is the same template CDK generated.

Comment: Hi @TsalTroser, If I use CDK, we can have some lines of code for retrieving the ARN, and based on found or not found we can conditionally define the values of the keys. For the new keys also we can use condition. I'd like to see if I can find a complete solution.

Comment: If you would like to make this your final answer, you may want to update some of your statements, so others don't get it wrong. For example, "You don't manually edit a resource managed via Cfn or IaC. It will create a drift in the template." is correct, but changing secret values manually is not "manually edit a resource managed via Cfn or IaC". So, that is not a mistake. Also, retrieving values using the `{{resolve::secretsmanager...}} and assigning back to the same secret is not a circular reference in this case. It is one time per update, and it works.

Comment: @Rafiq I update the answer and remove the those statements and made it clear. I also added some recommendation.